# Is this relationship a @OneToMany instance?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I already have two tables:

[zip_codes_germany](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs1n3.png)

and

[travel_agencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27or6.png)

filled with some data. Where **travel_agencies** has a composite key from columns **name** and **city** and **zip_codes_germany** has the primary key **zip_code**.

Let the condition be fulfilled that the city names are the same in both tables. Now one **city** maps to multiple **zip_codes**.

What is the best way to make this relationship clear in order to receive the correct list of zip codes when loading a TravelAgency object using hibernate?

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "travel_agencies")
public class TravelAgency implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5215122407119218666L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "ceo")
    private String ceo;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "city")
    private Set<ZipCodeArea> zipCodeAreas;
```

I'm new to hibernate and working with databases in general so I'm not quite sure if it is the correct tool to get what I'm asking for or if I'd better go with something else?

Comment: Ask yourself: can every `ZipCodeArea` only belong and be linked to a single `TravelAgency`? If the answer is Yes than OneToMany is the correct relationship, but if your answer is "No one ZipCodeArea can be linked to more than 1 TravelAgency" then the relationship is a ManyToMany.

Comment: Or in other words: If you would create a Backlink in your `ZipCodeArea` class would it be of type `private TravelAgency travelAgency` or would it be `private Set<TravelAgency> travelangencies`

Comment: You're right, then I have a ManyToMany relationship here. I do have the problem when implementing this though, that I do not get a List of ZipCodeAreas in my TravelAgency Object. My guess: because I can not use "city" alone as the foreign key in the @JoinTable annotation of the ManyToMany relation. How do I work around this? I'll add the code of this in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by OH GOD SPIDERS, I do have a many to many relationship here.